# cAjax mod_rewrite not working in codeigniter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am starting with cjax framework in codeigniter

as explained in the readme file i have setup all the things properly and

my cjax is working great but i wanted to remove the `.php` part from the url..

from `ajax.php?test/test` to `ajax/test/test` for this

i have written the following lines in my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^/?ajax\/(.*)$ /ajax.php?$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(ajax)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

but this is giving me 404 error.. any one please help..

thanks in advance

Comment: Is this the only code in your .htaccess OR there is more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /CIAjax/

RewriteRule  ^ajax/(.+)$ ajax.php?$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: when trying `http://localhost/CIAjax/ajax/test/test` with your suggested rules 404 error encounter and when `http://localhost/CIAjax/ajax.php?test/test` this it is working properly..and i want to remove the .php from the `ajax.php?test/test`

Comment: Is this .htaccess in `DocumentRoot` OR in `/CIAjax/`?

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH SIR..NOW WORKING GREAT AS ASPECTED..THANK YOU VERY MUCH SIR..FOR YOUR IMPORTANT TIME.. :)